# ¿Como hacer un aumento a un monto luego de haberse vencido la fecha de pago?

Tags: php

Saludos chicos, planteo mi problema:

Debo hacer un aumento del 15% a un monto pasados 5 días de la fecha en la que tubo que haber pagado la persona. Un ejemplo practico es:

Fecha Actual: 30-08-2017
Fecha del Pago: 25-08-2017
Total = monto + (monto * 0.15)

Como ven eso es lo que se debe cumplir en mis condicionales.

He intentado con esto:

```
$hoy = date('d-m-Y');
$fecha_pago = new DateTime($row['fecha_a_pagar']);
$fecha = new DateTime($hoy);
$diff = $fecha->diff($fecha_pago);

$multa = 0;
if($diff->days >= 5 && $diff->invert):
$multa = $row['monto']*0.15;
$total = $row['monto']+$multa;
endif;
```

Hace el aumento bien, pero cuando voy a pagar una cuota adelantada ej:

Fecha hoy: 30-08-2017
Fecha de cuota a pagar: 12-09-10

Me sigue haciendo el aumento, no me esta comparando los meses. Solo los días.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que podés hacer es usar el método diff que te da la diferencia entre dos fechas.
En este caso, podrías hacer:

```
<?php
        $d1=new DateTime("2017-12-25"); //$row['fecha_a_pagar']
        $d2=new DateTime(); //fecha actual
        $diff=$d2->diff($d1); 
        if($diff->days >= 5 && $diff->invert){
        //Cobrar multa
    }
?>
```

Comment: Lucrecia entonces me quedaria:                                                
$fecha_actual = new DateTime('d-m-Y');
  $fecha_pago = new DateTime($row['fecha_pago']);
  $diff = $fecha_pago->diff($fecha_actual);
  if($diff->days >= 5):
    $multa = $row['monto']*0.15;
    $total = $row['monto']+$multa;
    else:
    $multa = 0;                                                                                     
    $total = $row['monto'];

Comment: Alejo, si. Tenés que tener en cuenta el formato de la fecha que está en $row['fecha_pago'], debería ser 'Y-m-d'
Por otro lado, para que te quede el código más limpio, podrías setear la multa a 0 fuera del if y después hacer para todos los casos +$multa. Sería:
if($diff->days >= 5)
 $multa = $row['monto']*0.15; 
$total = $row['monto']+$multa;

Comment: Si he hecho eso Lucrecia, ahora tengo el problema de que si quiero hacer una pago adelantado por ejemplo hoy es 30-08-2017 y voy a pagar una cuota del 12-10-2017 el aumento me lo sigue haciendo, es como si solo comparara los dias y no los meses. El formato en el que guardo la fecha a pagar es d-m-Y. Sera por eso? Tendria que guardarlo en el formato que me dices para que funcione bien?

Comment: Alejo, en ese caso, tenés que validar también el atributo invert. Es 1 si el intervalo representa un periodo de tiempo negativo y 0 si no.

Comment: @AlejoMendoza ahí lo edité para que quede completo

Comment: Me sigue pasando lo mismo, editare mi pregunta sustituyendo el codigo que he puesto por el que tengo.

Comment: @AlejoMendoza fijate que estás restando las fechas al revés del ejemplo que puse. Si querés dejarlo en ese orden, entonces en el if poné !$diff->invert.
Por otro lado, lo de poner monto 0 era para que no tengas if:else.

Comment: He editado Lucrecia según tus correcciones, ahora creo que así debería funcionar.

Comment: Buenísimo! entonces marcá la respuesta como útil, para que les sirva a los que vienen. Saludos!

Comment: Perfecto, si ha funcionado. Muchas gracias de verdad.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64849/discussion-between-lucrecia-moralejo-and-alejo-mendoza).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función [date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.diff.php) que devuelve un objeto [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) con la diferencia de días, horas, minutos, etc.

Ejemplo modificado de la documentación de PHP:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
if($interval->d >= 5) {
    // realiza el aumento
}
?>
```

Comment: Zebrastorm, pero me esta tomando nada mas los dias. Por ejemplo si una persona quiere pagar cuotas adelantadas el aumento me sigue saliendo. Por ejemplo: fecha actual: 30-08-2017 y va a pagar una cuota del 24-12-2017, aun asi me sigue saliendo el aumento. Como podria hacer en ese caso, para que me tome el mes tambien.

Comment: Comprueba la respuesta de Lucrecia, la mía no tiene en cuenta esa posibilidad. Y releyendo la documentación lo correcto sería comprobar $interval->days. Saludos.